# Retrieve used header and source file names by parsing Makefile

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, gnu-make

I would like to extract all the `*.cc` and `*.h` filenames from a Makefile that also contains unused targets. Example Makefile here : https://gist.github.com/berceanu/7554a9c4371b807e425259c7e99b5de9

I've tried running `make -Bnd` and looking at the pruned files but I don't know if this misses anything.

`make -Bnd | grep "Pruning file" | sort | uniq`

Expected result: list of all `*.h` and `*.cc` files used by `make run` on the above Makefile.

Comment: If you're afraid one of the "unused" files is actually used, try removing all of the "unused" files, cleaning and rebuilding. If you're afraid one of the "used" files is actually unused, try touching them one by one and rebuilding after every touch. If you're worried about unnecessary dependencies -- which means unnecessary `#include` directives -- you'll probably have to comment them out one by one and see whether you can still compile.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not an option for large makefiles with hundreds of files. I would like an automated solution, in fact I already came up with one but it might not be complete. Another option would be to write a full parser in Python, but that is a lot of work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach trying to extract this information from the `Makefile` is probably the wrong way. `make` doesn't know which header files are *actually* used. `make` only knows which header files you've explicitely told `make` about in the dependencies, and that's not very reliable. The information in the `Makefile` could be wrong in two ways. It could contain unused targets (as you have noticed) or unused header files. It could miss header files that are actually included but not mentioned in the `Makefile`. Even worse, what if the actual inclusion of header files depends on macros, like `#ifdef XYZ_FEATURE #include "additionalHeaderFile.h" #endif`.

There are at least three ways how you could generate the desired list, that is, list of `.cc` and `.h` files actually used during compilation:

- (blindly trusts the `Makefile`) `make -n --print-data-base`
- (follows the real files of the build, but also a bit difficult to parse) `strace -f make`
- (relies on a feature present in GCC, clang, armcc and possibly other compilers for `Makefile` generation, very reliable) Add `CPPFLAGS:=-MMD` to the `Makefile`, run `make clean`, then `make`, then use `cat *.d` to get the list of all `.cc` and `.h` files used to build `run`. You could even do that without changing the `Makefile`: `make clean; make CPPFLAGS:=-MMD && cat *.d | sed -e 's/\\//g' -e 's/:/ /g' -e 's/ \+/\n/g' | sort -u`.

Also, the `Makefile` that you've shared in the gist has a large number of issues.

- The default target should, by convention, be named `all` [1](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Standard-Targets.html#Standard-Targets) [2](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Standard-Targets.html#Standard-Targets) [3](http://www.catb.org/esr/writings/taoup/html/ch15s04.html#id2987148). That doesn't need to be the name of the binary, it would just be a `.PHONY` target.
- The variable with the list of object files should be named `OBJS` or `OBJECTS`, not `OBJ`. The name `OBJ` is misleading, because it's singular.
- Instead of `rm` use `$(RM)` which implies `-f` and thus will not trouble in case a file doesn't exist. (As a side-effect, the `Makefile` would become more portable, as not all platforms use `rm` for deleting files.)
- `clean` is not a file and thus should be a `.PHONY` target.
- `clean` should use `::` instead of `:` for its recipe so that in future, when the `Makefile` is bigger and split into multiple files, each file can have their own `clean` target without problems.
- Variables that are not rule-specific should be expanded at the moment of definition, not when they are referenced, and thus defined using `:=` instead of `=`.
- Instead of `C++` use `CXX` which is already defined.
- Instead of putting the options into `C++`/`CXX`, use `LDFLAGS`, because you're linking.
- You should have a source file that has the same basename as the binary. Then you can use the built-in rule for linking.
- Explicit dependencies in the `Makefile` are a pain for maintenance. Every time an `#include` statement for a project header file is added, removed, or changed, the `Makefile` would have to be updated, and that's easy to forget, and it's a pain, especially when the `#include` statement is in a header file. Even with due diligence, this is also an invisible merge conflict. Instead of having explicit dependencies in the `Makefile`, you should use `CPPFLAGS+=-MMD` at the start of your `Makefile` and append `-include $(wildcard *.d)` at the end of your `Makefile`, and add `*.d` to the list of files to delete in `clean`. You could then remove *all* dependency rules from the `Makefile` (except for the one for the linkage).
- Naming the binary `run` is not a good idea. Users that see that your `Makefile` has a `run` target would expect this to *run* the actual program, not to link it.
- It is better to have each object mentioned on a line of its own. That significantly reduces merge conflicts in projects when multiple developers change the object list at the same time.

Your actual `Makefile` should look like this, with the binary renamed from `run` to `program`:

```
LDFLAGS:=-Wno-deprecated -lm
CPPFLAGS+=-MMD
BINARY:=program

OBJECTS:= \
    $(BINARY).o \
    binomh.o \
    # More objects here

.PHONY: all
all: $(BINARY)

$(BINARY): $(OBJECTS)

.PHONY: clean
clean::
    $(RM) \
        $(BINARY) \
        *.[adios] \

-include $(wildcard *.d)
```

That `Makefile` will do the "same" thing as your `Makefile`, but it is almost *maintenance-free*. No need to update dependencies, as they are automatically taken from the dependency files generated by the C Preprocessor. The `*.[adios]` will also remove files created in case you added `-save-temps` to any of the `CFLAGS`, `CXXFLAGS`, or `CPPFLAGS`.

This type of `Makefile` is known to work for GCC, clang, AOCC (AMD Optimizing C Compiler), and armcc. It probably works for a number of other compilers and preprocessors as well, especially when they are based on, or try to be compatible with, GCC or clang/LLVM.

BTW in case you're interested in knowing that this works for you, with high confidence, besides experience: I've taken your `Makefile` and added the following lines to it in order to reproduce your source code structure. The header files would just be empty files. The C++ source files would be lists of `#include` statements taken from the dependencies in your `Makefile`.

```
%.cc:
    grep '^$*\.o.*:' $(MAKEFILE_LIST) | sed -e 's/.*://' -e 's/.*$*\.cc//' -e 's/ \([^ ]\+\)/#include "\1"\n/g' >$@

%.h:
    touch $@
```

Comment: I really appreciate the amount of you you've put into this!
I'm trying it out and got : `Makefile:17: *** missing separator.  Stop.`
After removing the `clean` target I get:
`make: *** No rule to make target 'program.o', needed by 'program'.  Stop.`

Comment: Thanks. If the answer is helpful, please don't forget to upvote and/or accept it.

Comment: Do I still need to add all the \.o files from the original Makefile under OBJECTS?

Comment: Yes, at least as long as there are `.cc` files that you do _not_ want to compile. 

However, you could also write a `Makefile` that would simply compile all `*.cc` files it finds. Do this by using `OBJECTS:=program.o $(patsubst %.cc,%.o,$(wildcard *.cc))`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `-Bnd`, I would suggest using `--dry-run --print-data-base`  to dump the full database of targets, their dependencies, rules, variables, etc..

Comment: OK, but that results in an even-harder-to-parse output.

Comment: @redhotsnow IMO, the output is easily parseable.

Comment: So how could I extract the relevant .cc and .h files from it?